# Jump Menu Style Dropdown To External Links

Tags: views, 7, routes, users

I'm attempting to create a jump menu of links to external websites, and I would like to be able to order the links within this menu differently depending on the organic group of the current user attempting to access it. So far I've tried to accomplish this using views with nodequeue, and have come somewhat close, but its beginning to feel like a dead end..
 Does any module(or combination of modules exist) which would allow me to accomplish this without having to write my own?
Ideally each will be able to reorder the links according to their personal preference and override the default ordering of links. but that is not essential at this point

Answer (score 0):

you could create a node type link and a Views jump menu that loads said node types.

Comment: Please explain the process so that people except the OP can understand.

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried. I created a content type to try to do this already, however, views has NO option to use the Link field of node as a url in a jump menu..